# getElementsByClassName returns undefined even though the element is in the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to fetch some elements from the DOM of the page using `getElementsByClassName`. 
Seems simple enough, problem is that I always get undefined even though element itself is in the document (unless I misunderstood things).

Any idea why?

`document.getElementsByClassName('masonry-column')[0].getElementsByClassName('subject-details')[6]` returns `undefined`.

`document.getElementsByClassName('masonry-column')[0].getElementsByClassName('subject-details')` returns:

```
 [div.subject-details, div.subject-details, div.subject-details, div.subject-details, div.subject-details, item: function, namedItem: function]
    0: div.subject-details
    1: div.subject-details
    2: div.subject-details
    3: div.subject-details
    4: div.subject-details
    5: div.subject-details 
    6: div.subject-details // I need this element
    7: div.subject-details
    8: div.subject-details
    length: 9
    __proto__: HTMLCollection
```

Comment: And when are you running this, before or after Masonry's been called?

Comment: @DavidThomas I am calling this whenever the page DOM subtree is modified (have a listener for DOMSubtreeModified).

Comment: @RobG wrong phrasing. Will edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

I am fetching the elements too early. If for example I call my function after a few seconds delay, everything works as expected.

Comment: The general rule of thumb for DOM calls is to wait until the entire document is loaded.   Otherwise you have a race condition.  A`window.onload=function (){}` aught to do the trick